# Getting Error while downloading file: The process cannot access the file '[filepath]' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload, download, filestream

I have an application where I have to upload files and there is an option to download those files. When I upload file it works without any problem but the problem is with download option. When I try to download the upload file it shows below error message

**The process cannot access the file '[filepath]' because it is being used by another process.**

When I tried after say 30 minutes I didn't get any error but same error occurs if I upload new file and try to download it.

Below is my download and upload code. Please help me to figure out where is the problem.

**Upload**

```
FileStream fileStream = File.Create(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("myfile.pdf"), (int)filestream.Length);
byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[filestream.Length];
filestream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
```

**Download**

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.pdf");

FileStream sourceFile = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("myfile.pdf"), FileMode.Open);
long FileSize;
FileSize = sourceFile.Length;
byte[] getContent = new byte[(int)FileSize];
sourceFile.Read(getContent, 0, (int)sourceFile.Length);
sourceFile.Close();

HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(getContent);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

It looks like file was not release after upload but I don't know how to release that file after upload so that it may not create any problem while downloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. There was a small looking but a big mistake. I forgot to put below line at the end of my upload function:

```
fileStream.Dispose();
```

Because I didn't disposed the stream object my file was still in use by that object and I think garbage collector was releasing my file after some time that is why I was able to download that later.